# load html content with default dropdown selection value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load html page, based on dropdown selection. It works fine when selections are made. But want to load default page with default dropdown selection. Here is my code. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
iframe {
    display: block;       /* iframes are inline by default */
    background: #000;
    border: none;         /* Reset default border */
    height: 100vh;        /* Viewport-relative units */
    width: 100vw;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">

function showSelected(sel) {
  locations = ["",
    "/default.asp",
    "test2.html",
    "//example.com"
  ];

  srcLocation = locations[sel.selectedIndex];
  if (srcLocation != undefined && srcLocation != "") {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<iframe src="' + srcLocation +
      '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto"></iframe>';
    //document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "<br>Page Doesn't exists<br>";
  }
}

$(function() {
  $("select#page_selected").val("default.asp").change();
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="page_selected" onchange="showSelected(this);" onload="showSelected(this);">
  <option value="">select an option...</option>
  <option value="default.asp">Page 1</option>
  <option value="test2.html">Page 2</option>
  <option value="Page3.html">Page 3</option>
</select>
<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying when someone first comes to the page, it should load `default.asp`?

Comment: Yes. that is what I am trying for

Comment: Did any of the 3 answers below solve it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to below should do the work.

```
<select onchange="showSelected(this);" onload="showSelected(this);">
   <option value="">select an option...</option>
   <option value="default.asp" selected="selected">Page 1</option> 
   <option value="test2.html">Page 2</option> 
   <option value="Page3.html">Page 3</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason it just selects the "Page 1" option, but the default.asp page is not loaded by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your select does not have a `page_selected` id. Also there's a typo in default.asp

Without select id your code would have to be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == "default.asp";
  }).prop('selected', true);
  //showSelected();  
});
```

You could also use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select option[value='default.asp']").prop('selected', "selected");
  //showSelected();  
});
```

EDIT: to call the showSelected() after that, you'll need to pass in the $("select") object, but you could also just trigger the change event:

```
$("select").trigger("change");
```

Of course you'd want to add an id to your selectors!

EDIT: and you're not getting any errors in your console? For instance an error saying showSelected is not defined.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oc8xcyce/

Even shorter: set the select value: https://jsfiddle.net/oc8xcyce/1/

Comment: thanks for the inputs. I modified as you suggested, but still default page not loading.

Comment: Looks like this code is working fine in jsfiddle but it fails to select and load default selection page in my web browser (chrome). I have this entire code written in single html file with <head> <body> section. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser dev console?

Comment: In your single html file, are you including jquery library? (script src). You are aware that the $ stuff is jquery code?

Comment: Oh now I see this error in console "Uncaught ReferenceError: showSelected is not defined". I have included this in script src <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"> Please bare with me I am newbie to JavaScript and JQuery

Comment: You should close the script tag and open a new one for your js code. `<script src=".."></script><script>// your js code</script>`

Comment: Thanks a ton. yes It worked after keeping (script src) in head section and script function in body section...

Comment: Great! You didn't have to seperate scripts like that. Just never put code inside script with src attribute. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script and http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Well HTML have an attribute for this, you can simply use `selected` attribute in your wanted option:

```
<select onchange="showSelected(this);">
   <option value="">select an option...</option>
   <option selected value="default.asp">Page 1</option> 
   <option value="test2.html">Page 2</option> 
   <option value="Page3.html">Page 3</option> 
</select>
```